# Why is my Elasticseach API(_nodes/stats) getting stuck?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch v6.5.1 on a 40 nodes cluster with `analysis-icu` plugin installed.
When making a consecutive `_nodes/stats` to 40 nodes the request get stuck after a while. I have enabled trace logs for root as well as transport and slowlogs too which reveal that the query is being served in few milliseconds.
Any help is appreciated.